# ExpressJS: i want to fetch data from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, ejs

i am working on a project using **express , EJS and SQLite**, so i made  search operation function that fetch  data from the database, i want to display the data when i press  the button, not before it, this is the function i made :

```js
function findHomeforSell(req , res , next){
  const sell = "sell";
  db.all("SELECT * FROM home WHERE four like ?", [
    sell
  ] ,function(err , rows){
    if (err) { return next(err);}
    var homes = rows.map(function(row) {
      return {
        id: row.id,
        location: row.Location,
        four: row.four,
        space: row.space,
        bathrooms: row.bathrooms,
        bedrooms: row.bedrooms,
        price: row.price,
        url: '/' + row.id
      }
    });
    res.locals.homes = homes;
    next();
  });
};
```

This is the route that requested  when i press the button:

```js
router.get('/buyHome', ensureLoggedIn ,fetchData,findHomeforSell , findHomeforRent, (req , res , next) => {
  res.render('index', {user: req.user ,namor: res.locals.homes, rent: res.locals.rent});
  next();
});
```

This is **HTML** form :

```html
<form action="/buyHome" method="get">
                    <ul class="todo-list">
                        <% namor.forEach(function(namor) { %>
                            <li>
                                <div class="view" id="view">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                                <th>Location</th>
                                                <th>For</th>
                                                <th>Space</th>
                                                <th>Bathroom</th>
                                                <th>Bedroom</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="circul" alt=""></td>
                                            <td><%= namor.location %></td>
                                            <td><%= namor.four %></td>
                                            <td><%= namor.space %> SQRM</td>
                                            <td><%= namor.bathrooms %></td>
                                            <td><%= namor.bedrooms %> </td>
                                            <td>$ <%= namor.price %> SDG</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <% }); %>
                    </ul>
                <input type="button" value="GO">                    
            </form>
```

My problem is that the data appear before i call it or press the button

Comment: Please read [ask]. You've told us what you want to happen. You've shown us quite a lot of code. You haven't explained the problem. You haven't told  us what errors you get, if any. You haven't added logging to trace the values you are dealing with through the program (and you haven't told us the results of that).

Comment: If you've resolved your problem then either self-answer your question (**if** the solution is going to use useful for future visitors, which rather depends on the question being clear and focused in the first place) or delete it.

Comment: I DIDN'T SOVLED IT YET , I fixed the post

Comment: Relevant server code is missing. Who calls the function `findHomeforSell` ?  I believe you have used this function as middleware so it runs on every request.

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: Yes , i used it as middleware , because i couldn't call on specific request , So how i can call the function without put it as middleware?